# Toggle: retrieve image path from database dynamically

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic, toggle

I have a toggle button next to each recipes on my website. 
I have **images in my database** that I'd like to display. Each toggle button would display a different image.

How can i retrieve the **image path dynamically** ?

Should I had some php to my CSS or should I add something else to the Jquery code?

```
<div class="toggle"  id="image<?php echo $recipe_id ?>"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var $content = $(".content").hide();
$(".toggle").on("click", function(e){
$(this).toggleClass("expanded");
$(this).siblings('.content').toggle();
});
});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.toggle {
background:url(/images/muffin.png) }
```

Right now, all the toggle buttons display the same dummy image (muffin.png).

Comment: are you storing images or paths to images?

Comment: @Qweick Im storing paths to images. That's why i'm sure it's feasible to do it dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To list the recipes from your database you probably have a query like this somewhere:

```
SELECT * FROM recipes
```

And after that your PHP script probably loops through the results of this query.

If this is the case, just make sure the query selects the path to the image, then do something like this:

```
<div class="toggle" id="image<?php echo $recipe_id ?>" style="background:url(<?php echo $query_result["image_path"] ?>)"></div>
```

If this is not the case, you can execute a query to get the image paths for each recipe individually:

```
SELECT image_path FROM recipes WHERE recipe_id=$recipe_id
```

Then use the result from this query.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are a few ways to do this. You could echo out the path to the image while the page is being parsed in PHP, or you could use Ajax to connect to PHP, figure and the path and spit it back o JavaScript, where you could append the image tag to the DOM.

I would recommend using the later method, as it is more correct in my opinion. I see you are echoing $image_id. Try to do

```
<img href="<?php echo $image_path; ?>">
```

and let me know if that works. If not, can you specify the table name and column name where the image path is stored? Also are you using any PHP frameworks?

Comment: How is the latter method more correct? In my opinion it just adds unnecessary complication if you request one string of data every time the user clicks on a button, if that information was already available while the page was being generated.

Comment: @Jesbus I don't see the point of including content that's hidden by default anyway.

Comment: I'm also against loading content that's hidden, but two requests (AJAX, then the image) is unnecessary if you can make it one (just the image).